# Refresh Text Box (Document) in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

I am writing a program which will run and refresh a bunch of Excel Files and Textbox Documents within the file. Using the `.RefreshAll()` Method, I can refresh the linked tables within the file, as well as the text documents that are linked. However, one function I need to add is to refresh the documents without updating the tables.

After searching on here, and MDSN, I can't seem to pinpoint the thing I need. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update links to Excel files and not the Linked Data Tables (ListObjects), then you can just iterate through each link and refresh it individually:

```
using Excelx = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excelx.Workbook wb = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;

object links = wb.LinkSources(Excelx.XlLink.xlExcelLinks);
Array linkz = (Array)links;

for (int i = 1; i <= linkz.Length; i++)
{
    wb.UpdateLink(linkz.GetValue(i).ToString(), Excelx.XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks);
}
```

The initial part seems like it could theoretically be compressed, but I've never had much luck consolidating those statements.